# SourceTree left pane view spinning, won't load

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I recently upgraded to SourceTree 2.0.20.1.  After that upgrade one of my projects won't load the left pane.  It just sits with the windows busy spinning icon (see attached image).  All my other projects seem to load fine.  The history shows fine and I can commit to the repository, just can't view my branches in the left pane.  All my project remotes reside on the same VSO git server.  Any ideas?

[SourceTree Left Pane View Spinning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9DR2.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using git, try running `git fsck` in the a command line.

The sourcetree left-hand panel was not loading for me either.
I had errors reported by `git fsck`, but once I resolved those errors, sourcetree worked correctly again.